# Ubuntu + Jmeter : Execution results are not showing in console while running test in Non GUI mode (Distributed Test)

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a distributed test from ubuntu machine using JMeter. When I am running test from master machine the results ( Active threads, Avg Resp time) details not showing in console,

tried by adding "Console status logger" Lisner. Still, it's not showing the results.

[image]

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it so that it's useful to others

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons for that are the following:

- You don't have enough results yet, see [doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote_batching_config), properties **time_threshold**, **num_sample_threshold**
- You have a connectivity issue between slaves and master, see this [doc](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) and this [one](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html). This might be due to a Firewall between those components, ensure you open required ports.

Comment: I have waited for more than 35 min and scripts are running in the slave machines because I am able to see CPU utilization of the slave machines and the target server.

Comment: So it's the second hypothesis. Check jmeter.log of jmeter servers and client

Comment: I am able to see the results after updating the value of time_threshold, num_sample_threshold. Thank you

Comment: As I wrote please check connectivity , which is the second proposal